# Create a board from a vector of vectores

Tags: c++, vector

I'm having some issues creating a board from a vector of vectors

I need something like

```
  a b c d e f g h i j 
A . . . . . . . . . .
B . . . . . . . . . .
C . . . . . . . . . .
D . . . . . . . . . .
E . . . . . . . . . .
F . . . . . . . . . . 
G . . . . . . . . . .
H . . . . . . . . . .
I . . . . . . . . . .
J . . . . . . . . . .
```

The size can change (depends on some txt info that I already "extracted" on the constructor). 
I tried something like this:

```
 void Board::display() const{

//string filename;
Board b1("configp1.txt");

int upC = 65, lowC = 97; //ascii code for low a and upper A
int icc = 0; //int char coluna

cout << b1.numLines << endl;
cout << b1.numColumns << endl;
cout << "lol" << endl;

for(int i = 0; i < b1.numLines; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < b1.numColumns; j++){
        board[i][j] == '.';
    }
}


while (icc < b1.numLines){ //o int char coluna vai aumentando consoante as dimensoes do tabuleiro || e.g Se tivermos um tab 10x10
    cout << (char)lowC << " ";                      //teremos um range de 65-75 [a-j] para as colunas e um range 97 -107 [A-J] para as linhas
    icc++;
    lowC++;
}
cout << endl;
icc = 0;

for (int y = 0; y<b1.numLines; y++)
{
    cout << (char)upC << " ";
    for (int x = 0; x < b1.numColumns; x++){
        cout << board[y][x] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
    upC++;
}
```

Board Constructor:

```
Board::Board(const string &filename){


string nome;
unsigned int size;
char simb;
unsigned int cor;
char ori;
PositionChar position;


string tmp;
ifstream config;
config.open(filename.c_str()); //abre o ficheiro config onde estao as informacoes do tabuleiro

if (config.is_open()) {

    config >> tmp >> numLines >> tmp >> numColumns;

    while (!config.eof()) {

        config >> simb >> tmp >> position.lin >> position.col >> tmp >> ori >> tmp >> size >> tmp >> cor;

        if(!config.fail()){
            ships.push_back(Ship(simb, position, ori, size, cor));
        }


    }
}

else{
    cout << "Ficheiro de config invalido" << endl;
    exit(1);
}
config.close();
```

}

Board class:

```
    class Board {
public:
    Board(const string &filename);
    int putShip(const Ship &s);
    void moveShips();
    //bool checkLimits()
    //bool attack(const Bomb &b);
    void display()const;
    void show()const;
    int getLines();
    int getColumns();

private:
    int numLines, numColumns;
    vector<Ship> ships;
    vector <vector <int> > board;

};
```

But nothing happens at all.

Can someone help me please??

Best regards

Comment: How you initialized board variable. Woukd be useful if you paste a compilable example

Comment: Edited. I printed the b1.numLines and b1.numColumns and it is working pretty fine btw

Comment: Whow is board[][] defined ?  Can you also give us the classdefinition of Board ?  Are you sure that b1.getlines() is not null ?

Comment: How board is related to b1?

Comment: Class and constructor added - thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your board is defined as a vector of vector: `vector <vector <int> > board;`

But in the constructor, you don't initialize it. Neither do you in the display function. So its empty.  Trying to access `board[i][j]` would in this case be out of bounds.

### Solution:

I'd suggest in the constructor, as soon as the dimensions are known to resize your vector(s) with:

```
    board.resize(numLines, vector<int> (numColumns,'.'));
```

### Other problems:

Please note that the following code shouldn't be in `display() const` as you intend to modify `board`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < b1.numLines; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < b1.numColumns; j++){
        board[i][j] == '.';    /// <=======OOOPS !  Won't change anything this is comparison
    }
}
```

This could compile only because you wrote `==`, so comparing `board[i][k]` with `'.'`  without changing it. This could explain why nothing happens  (displaying 0 will not produce anything visible).

Note that there's also another potential issue in `Board::display()`.  You create there a local variable `Board b1` in order to use `b1.numLines` and `b1.numColumns`.  This is error prone:  you should get rid of this useless `b1` and directly refer to `numLines` and `numColumns`, which are both member variables, with the advantage of being sure to get the values that you've set for your object in its own constructor.

Comment: Well, your answer was superb! Thank you so much. It is printing now, but instead of '.' , its printing 46 all over. I guess it's because an ints vector and I'm filling it with chars, right?

Comment: Exactly  !  If it's only a chararcter game make it a vector<char>.  But if you need it to remain in,  you could as well try `cout << (char)board[y][x] << " ";`